# How to make a call via Google Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, google-chrome, audio, remote-desktop

I am using Google Remote Desktop to access my company laptop which has a software installed for making phone calls. Now, I would like to use that software from my pc at home to make a call.

I can hear the audio (it gets duplicated to my pc), but the software does not use my microphone (input), so I am involuntarily muted.

**How can I use my mic as audio input over Google Remote Desktop?**

---

PS: http://www.sound-over-rdp.com/sound-over-rdp.html would actually work, but they don't support Google Remote Desktop unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that Google Chrome Remote Desktop supports sending client audio back to the remote. If you really want to do this, what you can look into is sending and streaming your audio over IP through a separate application. This will probably require software on both your client computer and your remote computer.

[vban](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/vban.htm) might be able to do this inside of [Voicemeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm)... But you would have to configure the virtual mixer on both devices to correctly collect audio and send it to the right sources for the transmission. This can get a bit confusing even on a single local system. Note that Voicemeeter provides virtual audio input and output devices that applications can see like hardware. Then you can mix/connect/configure these in Voicemeeter.

If vban doesn't work for this purpose, you can use another software like skype to handle the transmission. You would route the other software as an audio source in voicemeeter, send that as a source for skype, then skype your client computer, which has your mic back to the skype on remote, which attaches to another virtual input of voicemeeter, routed to another virtual output that is in the remote software you want to use... think of this like connecting wires, one step at a time. There will probably be a lot of latency doing this though.

You would also have to be careful of audio feedback, and should probably use headphones...

Voicemeeter sometimes has hiccups and needs to be rebooted. And sometimes you still need to review the audio settings of each application, the computer, and even Vol Mixer settings if you are on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Google Chrome Remote Desktop does not support microphone redirection. If you are using windows system, why not use mstsc (microsoft remote desktop) to remote connect to your office computer, which support microphone redirection.

[image]

Also, you can download Microsoft Remote Desktop app, which also support microphone redirection. [Get Microsoft Remote Desktop - Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

Comment: Does Microsoft Remote Desktop require a special port? Because the laptop will be behind the company firewall and not easy to reach...

Comment: I am actually unable to create a remote desktop connection with my laptop, even when it is at home. It is just way too complicated compared to Google Remote Desktop

Comment: The error message translates to: "The session was closed. Your connection was disconnected because there was another connection to the remote computer." I don't get it, I just make one connection. I assume this is just a security measure taken by my company to avoid connections from outside.

Comment: Need to open port 3389 for RDP connection. For the error "Your connection was disconnected because there was another connection to the remote computer." This might be because your Google Chrome Remote Desktop has a connection, you might not totally logged it off.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't open any (new) port due to company policy

Comment: Good news: we actually could make it work now using Windows Remote Desktop. However, when I make a call, the audio quality is much worse now. Neither comparable to the quality on the remote pc, nor to the audio quality I have with Teams directly. It sounds metallic. Can this be improved?

Comment: It works now - however, when I make a call, the other person hears himself with an echo. And that even when I use head phones! Any idea how to solve this?